How to run command in ternux command from another app
I created code, which launch termux:
PackageManager pm = Editor.this.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.termux");

Also i added to manifest some args:
<queries>
        <package android:name="com.termux" />
    </queries>

I have .sh file in Documents folder and i want to run it when i pressed btn:
// Додаємо команду для виконання у Termux
                        intent.putExtra("com.termux", "bash /storage/emulated/0/Documents/GenCoreLite/scripts/build_script.sh");
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        startActivity(intent);

And nothing happened. So what i need from all this stuff:
When i pressed the btn termux is opened and automaticly launch command which launch .sh file from Douments folder
